# how to find minus from 2 data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to find sum. I want to ask how to (-) data from `total_bayaran` and `total_denda` from this code

```
select nama_penerjemah, nama_projek, SUM(bayaran) AS total_bayaran, SUM(denda) AS TOTAL_denda 
FROM tbl_episode 
GROUP BY nama_penerjemah, nama_projek
```

For example I have data 200 and 100
so, the result will be 200-100 = 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract them.

```
SELECT select nama_penerjemah, nama_projek, 
    SUM(bayaran) AS total_bayaran, SUM(denda) AS TOTAL_denda, 
    SUM(bayaran) - SUM(denda) AS total_difference
FROM tbl_episode 
GROUP BY nama_penerjemah, nama_projek
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
select nama_penerjemah, nama_projek,(Q1.total_bayaran-Q1.total_denda) total_diff from ( select nama_penerjemah, nama_projek, SUM(bayaran) AS total_bayaran, SUM(denda) AS TOTAL_denda 
FROM tbl_episode 
GROUP BY nama_penerjemah, nama_projek) Q1
```